# Flattening a resized image - AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm in an introductory neural networks class (very basic programming knowledge).

I'm trying to flatten an image which I've resized to (50,50). Using `img_resized = img.resize((2500,1))` worked, but I was told that the resize function isn't ideal for flattening a 2D array into a 1D array. Instead, I'm trying to use the `flatten` tool:

```py
count=0
path1 = "/Users/..."
path2 = "/Users/..."
listing = os.listdir(path1)  
for file in listing:
    type = imghdr.what((path1 + file))
    if type == "jpeg":   
        img = Image.open("/Users/..." +file).convert('LA')
        img_resized = img.resize((50,50))
        img_resized = img_resized.flatten()
        img_filename = file.split(".")[0]
        img_resized.save(path2 + img_filename + '.png')
        count +=1
    pass
pass
```

This gave me the error message `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'flatten'`

I'm not sure how to introduce the flatten attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what module you're using for Image processing, but I'm going to assume it's Pillow. The error is clear - there is no function named `flatten` in the `Image` class, and the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html) confirm that.

It's not completely clear what you mean by flatten, but I assume you mean take each row of the image and append that row to the end of the previous row so that every pixel is laid out in a single long row. The `Image.resize` function should not accomplish this because it will just stretch the image (imagine if you were using Microsoft Paint to resize the image). You could accomplish this with the `Image.getdata` function ([link](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=flatten#PIL.Image.Image.getdata)), which returns a sequence containing flattened pixel values for the image. You would then have to convert that sequence back into an image and then save that. Always remember to refer to the docs of the library you're using for all the information about what can be accomplished with that library.